# make eclipse javadoc my project

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, javadoc

Is there a way to make eclipse go through my project and add javadoc to all the method headers? Possible authors to the classes?

Comment: Assuming you'll need to individually write the javadoc for each one of your methods and classes anyway, why not just use the built-in feature of typeing `/**` and `enter` above each method/class?

Comment: You can also hit Alt+Shift+J and Eclipse will auto-generate an empty javadoc header for the member/method/class at the current cursor location.  It'll list your userid as the @Author for classes, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know this feature does not exist, although there might be a plugin that does it.

I would also advise strongly against this. JavaDoc should provide information to developers where needed, not cover the code in a blanket of generated (soon out of date) twaddle.

Comment: Agreed. Empty javadoc tags are completely useless. You should look to strip out these tags, rather than create more of them.